# I'm getting the following error after generating a schema and clicking on build, could this be due to having underscores and dashes in the table name?

Tags: cube.js

Compiling schema:

```
{"version":"default_schema_version_78dca52738894dbb23e7069f2e88ae73"}
Internal Server Error: {"authInfo":{"iat":1570115494,"exp":1570201894}}

Error: Compile errors:
test_1-stats cube: child "name" fails because ["name" with value "test_1-stats" fails to match the identifier pattern]
    at ErrorReporter.throwIfAny (/home/ec2-user/hello-world/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/schema-compiler/compiler/DataSchemaCompiler.js:42:13)
    at DataSchemaCompiler.throwIfAnyErrors (/home/ec2-user/hello-world/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/schema-compiler/compiler/DataSchemaCompiler.js:168:23)
    at repository.dataSchemaFiles.then.then (/home/ec2-user/hello-world/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/schema-compiler/compiler/DataSchemaCompiler.js:100:14)
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.

The cube.js schema does not allow dashes in names.

Remove any dashes in the database / table names to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain rules to follow for a cube and cube member names. You can use only 0-9, _, and letter characters when naming a cube or a cube member. Names should always start with a letter.

https://cube.dev/docs/cube#naming